# status 503 when heroku node app try to access to mlab db add-on with monk

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, mlab, monk

I'm trying to deploy my express-mongodb app on heroku. I've already tryed to access locally to the heroky mlab addon and with the local server works fine. But when I start the same server on heroku it looks like the server can't solve the requests because of the db lack. I'm wondering if the problem is with monk js or something else.

---

```
<!-- language: lang-javascript-->

const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const monk = require('monk');
    const engines = require('consolidate');

    const app = express();

    const router = require('./routes/router');


    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
    app.set('views', `${__dirname}/templates`);
    app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    const db = monk('mongodb://<xxxx>.mlab.com:15338/heroku_1xx37v0b');
    db.then(() =>{
      console.log("connection success");
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.error("Error !",e);
    });
    app.use((req, res, next) => { req.db = db; next(); });

    app.use('/', router);

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);


    // ask something to the db
    const collection = db.get('docUtenti');
    collection.findOne({type: "docTotUtenti" }).then((doc) => {console.log(doc);})
```

Comment: Did you set  up the port env variable? (I know it does not relate to mongo but, might help)

Comment: no actually ... I though that was enougth this way, how can I set it? I'm using the express js app structure, is it related with the www folder?

Comment: I think I was wrong with that. I might was spleepy when was reading the post. So anyway the PORT en var is set up by definition. But deploying the up you need a couple of thing. Specify the node version in the package.json file, and add a start script as well. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: I just finished a chat with the heroku support. And it looks that the problem is made somehow  because of monk itself. Maybe i should just move to Mongoose.